# When doing an OUTER JOIN to a table how can I join in another table to the one on the Right of the outer Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an ASP.Net Sql Server 2012 application and I am trying to create a report from four tables with SQL. I have a problem getting data for one field (the Status) field.

I have four tables:

- AdminTest - Available tests
- AdminTestQuestions - Test questions
- UserTest  - Tests a user has purchased
- UserTestStatus - A reference table (with two columns: UserTestStatusId and Name)

What I would like to do is to create a report like this which shows the case of test ABC that has an antry in the AdminTest and UserTest tables and the test DEF which has an entry only in the AdminTest table:

```
Code PurchaseDate  Questions Status
ABC  2012/1/1      50        Available
DEF                25        Purchase Now
```

Initially there would be only AdminTest rows and no UserTest available to join to. This is handled okay with the LEFT OUTER JOIN. When the user purchases a test then there will be an entry in the purchase date and I will be able to join the UserTest and UserTestStatus columns.

If there is no user test then I would like the status to be set "Purchase now"

Here's what I have so far. It only works if there is an AdminTest and UserTest table for a particular test code.

```
SELECT   AdminTest.Code        AS Code,     
         UserTest.PurchaseDate AS PurchaseDate,
         COUNT(AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId) AS Questions,
         UserTestStatus.Name   AS Status
FROM     AdminTest LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTest ON  AdminTest.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId 
                                            AND UserTest.UserId = @UserId
JOIN     AdminTestQuestion ON  AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
                           AND AdminTest.ExamId = @ExamId
                           AND AdminTest.TestStatusId = 3
JOIN     UserTestStatus    ON  UserTest.TestStatusId = UserTestStatus.UserTestStatusId 
GROUP BY AdminTest.Code,
     UserTest.PurchaseDate, 
     UserTestStatus.Name
```

So the joins need to look like this:

```
AdminTest >>> AdminTestQuestions
          >>> UserTest (optional) >>> UserTestStatus
```

Can someone give me some advice as to how I can get the data for the Status to be either equal to the words "`Purchase Now`" or to be the actual status if there is a `UserTest` that has been purchased.

**Update:**

Here's an answer that was proposed. I included this and also the output of the three selects below. I hope that helps to show the data. I can add anything else here to show more data if needed.

Select 1:

```
SELECT Code, AdminTestId 
FROM AdminTest
```

Output

```
Code    AdminTestId
abcdef  131
ddddddd 1130
```

Select 2:

```
SELECT AdminTestId, UserTestId 
FROM UserTest
```

Output

```
AdminTestId UserTestId
131           202
```

Select 3:

```
SELECT AdminTestQuestionId, AdmintestId, QuestionUId
FROM AdminTestQuestion
```

Output

```
3094    131     3CEFF956-BF61-419E-8FB2-9D6A1B75B909
4094    1130    5D679FAD-2904-45A1-AA5F-3DB16850438D
4095    1130    96EA8351-FA2B-4DB3-862D-260CA085563A
```

Select 4:

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserTestStatus
```

Output:

```
0   Available
1   Started
2   Paused
3   Finished
4   Marked
```

The Solution:

```
SELECT   temp.Code,     
         temp.Questions,
         UserTest.PurchaseDate AS PurchaseDate,
         (CASE 
              WHEN UserTestStatus.Name  IS NULL THEN 'Purchase Now'
              ELSE UserTestStatus.Name
         END)  AS Status
FROM
(SELECT   AdminTest.Code        AS Code,  
          AdminTest.AdminTestId,   
          COUNT(AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId) AS Questions
 FROM     AdminTest 
 JOIN     AdminTestQuestion ON  AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
                           AND AdminTest.TestStatusId = 3
 GROUP BY AdminTest.Code, AdminTest.AdminTestId) temp
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTest       ON  temp.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTestStatus ON  UserTest.TestStatusId = UserTestStatus.UserTestStatusId
```

Here's what I need to see:

```
Code    PurchaseDate            Questions Status
abcdef  2014-10-17 15:27:31.760    1      Available
ddddddd null                       1     Purchase Now
```

Comment: can you provide sample data for the tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It only works if there is an AdminTest and UserTest table for a
>   particular test code.

The reason this happens is because your join condition `UserTest.UserId = @UserId` is limiting the results to have `UserId` in UserTest for the join to happen. This needs to be changed to `AdminTest.UserId = @UserId`. Here I assume you are storing the `UserId` in `AdminTest` too as into `UserTest` has only entries when the user purchases

> If there is no user test then I would like the status to be set
>   "Purchase now"

For this to happen you need to use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

```
     CASE 
          WHEN UserTestStatus.Name  IS NULL THEN 'Purchase Now'
          ELSE UserTestStatus.Name
     END
```

**UPDATE**: ( based on OP's updates to questions)

One more this wrong in the original query was using `GROUP BY` `PurchaseDate` and `UserTestStatus` which is causing the current output.

Thus you final query will be

```
SELECT   temp.Code,     
         temp.Questions,
         UserTest.PurchaseDate AS PurchaseDate,
         (CASE 
              WHEN UserTestStatus.Name  IS NULL THEN 'Purchase Now'
              ELSE UserTestStatus.Name
         END)  AS Status
FROM
(SELECT   AdminTest.Code        AS Code,  
          AdminTest.AdminTestId,   
          COUNT(AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestQuestionId) AS Questions,
 FROM     AdminTest 
 JOIN     AdminTestQuestion ON  AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
                           AND AdminTest.TestStatusId = 3
 GROUP BY AdminTest.Code) temp
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTest       ON  temp.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTestStatus ON  UserTest.TestStatusId = UserTestStatus.UserTestStatusId
```

Comment: does the `AdminTest` have `UserId` column?

Comment: I updated my answer with your code and the output it gives. No the AdminTest does not have a userId. Note I simplified the code a bit and took out the userId and examId. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you make the current output with the columns names and some formatting? it will be more clear to me

Comment: @SamanthaJ Thanks for the update. Can clearly mention your input, current output and desired output separately. Make sure to add table name for input.

Comment: I added some more details. If you need more please let me know and I can add very quickly or try something else.

Comment: Thanks for the update please added  AdminTestQuestion and
UserTestStatus tables data as well make sure you have all the columns used in the query in the data like purchase date is missing form user test table

Comment: I think I added all that you need. Can you let me know if you need more. thanks

Comment: I understood whats causing the current output updating the code

Comment: Updated the answer can you try now?

Comment: Thanks - This worked! I made one small change with the group by. Great job. I will accept now :-)